# Swap configuration on local-SSDs

Tags: debian, swap, solid-state-drive, aerospike

I'm facing a problem using Aerospike on Highmem8 / 30Go machines with local-SSDs. We have configured 2 Go swap on the SSD.

Configuring Aerospike using the entire SSD disk, its formatted and shows "used 100%" which is normal.

But the swap is still activated.

Is there a possibility that if the system tries to use the swap (for some connections for example) the Debian OS no more responds?

In some cases, we can ping the remote machine, but can no longer connect to it through ssh and must destroy it.

Comment: - What is highmem-8, is this GCE?
- What is 30Go? Is this 30 GiB?
- Are you saying you have configured a 2 GiB swap device on a local SSD?
- If so are you using the same SSD for swap that you are using for Aerospike Data? (that would be a really bad thing to do)

Comment: is this related to programming? if not, [so] is the wrong forum; consider migrating your question to [sf] or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you are taking a high risk by sharing the same disk for Aerospike data and swap data. Each can effect the other. A better way out of this situation is to partition the drive. Say the drive is /dev/sdc, you can make one 2GB partition for swap and the rest of it for Aerospike data. In the aerospike configuration, you can specify the partition also (like /dev/sdc2). Its not necessary to give the whole drive to Aerospike's namespace.